# Python - How to check if functions are replacing each other with multiple `from ... import *` statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, python-import

I'm writing a testing suite that is one "master" test module that imports other test modules that each define the functions and variables necessary to run its tests. There are multiple collaborators, so I want to include a check in the "master" module for multiple definitions of functions and/or variables with the same names.

I've tried using the built-in `dir` function, which returns a list of names of defined variables and functions. The problem with this is that if I check this list each time I import new functions/variables, there is no way to know if one function/variable has replaced another with the same name since it was already there originally.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# this code shows that dir won't work
print(dir()) # does not contain "sys"
import sys
print(dir()) # now contains "sys"
def sys():
    return
print(dir()) # still contains "sys", can't tell that it was replaced

# this is the type of code I'm trying to write
from test_case_0 import *
check_for_replaced_functions_and_variables()
from test_case_1 import *
check_for_replaced_functions_and_variables()
from test_case_2 import *
check_for_replaced_functions_and_variables()
```

`check_for_replaced_functions_and_variables` should raise some sort of `Exception` if a function/variable has been replaced by the preceding import statement.

Comment: Don't use `from ... import *`, and this won't be a problem.

Comment: why don't you just **not use** `from some_module import *`, as is typically recommended?

Comment: Iterate through the directory one level down.  Maintain a set of `id`s.  After each import, see that no `id` is missing from the previous set.

Comment: Note, from PEP8: "There is one defensible use case for a wildcard import, which is to republish an internal interface as part of a public API (for example, overwriting a pure Python implementation of an interface with the definitions from an optional accelerator module and exactly which definitions will be overwritten isn't known in advance)." so, the only time you *should* be using this is when you *want* the overwriting behavior.